# SSLVerifyClient not asking for certificate

Tags: apache, ssl-certificate, virtualhost

When I put the directives:

```
SSLVerifyClient require
SSLVerifyDepth  2
SSLCertificateFile cert/path/cert.crt
```

Inside a virtual host directive and then go to the website a pop up box does not ask for my certificate. However when I put the same directives before  the virtual host it will.

Why does it act this way?

The documentation actually says the SSL directives listed should be defined inside the virtual host.